# Super lightweight car trailer?

Tags: trailer

I own a Tesla Model 3 and am seriously considering getting a tow-hitch for it. In the EU it is rated to tow up to 2,000lbs, so if I was to tow things on a trailer, the trailer being lightest weight would be ideal.

Can someone advise if there is already plans out to build your own out of super lightweight, but strong, materials to maximise the possible weight of the actually towed items?

-OR-

Can someone advise what the lightest weight trailer is to purchase?

Comment: I've been towing a [1195lb 4x8' trailer from the Harb](https://www.harborfreight.com/1195-Lbs-Capacity-48-in-x-96-in-Heavy-Duty-Folding-Trailer-62648.html) with my VW GTI (also as far as I remember rated for 2000lbs in the EU) for a few years without any trouble at all. It's got a sheet of 3/4" plywood for a deck. Survived 100's of short trips (10-20 miles) + 2 heavily-loaded round-trips between Atlanta & Orlando without any trouble.

Comment: Something [like this](https://www.tractorsupply.com/tsc/product/carry-on-trailer-5-ft-x-8-ft-open-mesh-floor-utility-trailer) only weighs about 400 lbs empty.  A 4x8 mesh floor would be marginally lighter.  There are also "folding" utility trailers that are very light - you need to decide what you want to carry.

Comment: Also cross posted : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/29555/10902

Comment: @brhans - Any idea on what this weighs? I am pretty serious about keeping under the 2,000lbs. I intend/expect to be able to keep this car for far longer than most gasoline cars considering the far less moving parts that can break down and be costly to repair, so wouldn't want to stress the motor more than rated, but not much point in getting a trailer that weighs even 1/3 of the towing capability.

Comment: The product listing has it at 253lbs and the plywood is probably about 55-60lbs - so about 310lbs together, which seems realistic (having dragged it around more than a few times). I also welded up a set of 2' high removable side panels for mine, so those probably add about an extra 100lbs all together if I use them.